Getting `bash: docker-compose: command not found` even though Docker for mac is installed
I have Docker installed for my web development class and in the folders we pull from github, it comes with docker-compose.yml and FlaskApp already included into it. I make sure to run the terminal at the folder.
But when I try to run docker-compose
This is the direct command:
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p hw2-container up
It always returns the error
-bash: docker-compose: command not found
How could this be possible?
I tried looking up the answer online. When I do it diverts me tot he same page where it tells me to remove the hiphon in the "docker-compose" but that also doesn't work.

This is a shell/terminal sysadmins basics problem, not a docker-compose problem. A good clean solution won't be a single step (although a hacky one might, better to avoid the mess it can leave behind), so just to get you started, look into terms: shell startup files, bash shell/zsh shell, PATH, shell which

What error are you getting when you try without the hyphen, aka: docker compose  up -f docker-compose.yml -p hw2-container?

Docker and docker-compose are two separate packages, so most probably you have installed docker but not docker-compose
I'd suggest to start verifying if docker-compose is present in your system by executing:
docker compose version
it should replay with something like:
Docker Compose version v2.29.1-desktop.1
docker-compose.yml is just a config file to define all containers and all its configs, so in order to use it you should have previously installed docker-compose package in your system
